# Hot to get unmatched rows in the end of result while doing outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I am trying a left outer join like this

```
SELECT records.some_id FROM forms 
LEFT OUTER JOIN records
ON forms.form_id = records.form_id
ORDER BY records.some_id
```

This will give me all the results from table:forms including some where records.form_id is not present. However, the returned result has unmatched rows in the beginning, how can I get them in last?

Current result:

```
NULL
NULL
5
20
100
```

Expected is:

```
5
20
100
NULL
NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `case`. Generally you can do

```
SELECT records.some_id FROM forms 
LEFT OUTER JOIN records
ON forms.form_id = records.form_id
ORDER BY case when records.some_id is not null 
              then 1 
              else 2 
         end,
         records.some_id
```

and specifically in MySQL you can also do

```
SELECT records.some_id FROM forms 
LEFT OUTER JOIN records
ON forms.form_id = records.form_id
ORDER BY records.some_id is not null,
         records.some_id
```

Comment: +1 . . . Although in MySQL, you don't need `case`.  You can just do `order by records.some_id is null desc`.

Answer (score 0):

Also putting a COALESEC might help

```
SELECT records.some_id FROM forms 
LEFT OUTER JOIN records
ON forms.form_id = records.form_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(records.some_id,-1) DESC
```

Comment: This will simply place all NULL rows together, but won't sort rest of rows.

Comment: Did you try this ? because i think this will place all the null at the end and will sort rest of the numbers in descending order .